# What is the Cache memory limit in spark by default?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

What is the maximum limit of cache in spark. How much data can it hold at once?

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview). It is `0.6 x (JVM heap space - 300MB)` by default.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but to my understanding here is calculation

What is executer memory.  Lets say it is 1 GB.

Then heap size is 0.6 of it which 600 MB

Then 50% of heap size is cache.  i.,e 300 MB.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview  in this,  they must have assumed executor memory is 500 MB.  In fact, for local executor memory default size is 500 MB.  If it executer memory is 500 MB then only 150 MB is allocated to cache

Answer (score 0):

Its Actually totally depends on executor memory. Spark will take as much as large part of the RDD in memory and the rest will be fetched and recomputed on the fly each time they're needed. It is totally configurable and you can check it [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)